# recent version of FOSTwitterBundle

Tags: symfony, twitter

In my symfony project i would like to implement a twitter inscription button, and
i'm searching about the most recent version of FOSTwitterBundle(version 1.1).
the version which i found is not compatible with symfony2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the FOSTwitterBundle has no released versions yet for current symfony versions. You have to use the dev-master branch.

```
"require": {
    "kertz/twitteroauth": "*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/twitter-bundle": "*@dev"
}
```

Comment: Thank's for response, i have used the dev-master branche with symfony 2.2.1 but i have problems, i have changed the minimum-stability to dev, shoud'i change the version symfony to 2.0? in the officiel web site of symfony there's not this version. where can i find it?

Comment: you still can use prefer stable, simply use `"friendsofsymfony/twitter-bundle": "1.*@dev"` to get latest version of the bundle

Comment: Only dev-master is compatible with 2.1 and upwards. the 1.0.x-dev branch is 2.0 only

Comment: I can use the 2.2.1 symfony version with FOSTwitterBundle using "friendsofsymfony/twitter-bundle": "1.*@dev" ?? Sorry I don't understand

Comment: Wah, i hate packages, which are not releasing any versions. Tested it, you need the requires as above in my edit. `minimum-stability` can remain `stable`.

Comment: so what is the solution??i can't install the 2.0 version and begin from 0 my project :(

Comment: I never said you should install 2.0! I provided you the composer constraint to use in actual symfony versions!